# How can I position the footer to be hidden under everything as shown below?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the footer from this website. https://pulice.com/.

As you can see the footer is hidden under the other sections only to be revealed as you scroll all the way to the bottom.

I used my dev tools and found that the position on the footer is fixed. I did the same to mine and this creates two problems.

- 1st the footer covers my stats section as you scroll up, z-index does
  nothing here.
- 2nd the footer section is not revealed when the user scolls to the bottom  of the page, instead it is hidden behind the section above it.

Can I get some help on these two problems?

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*---HEADER---*/

header {
  background-image: url(img/wall2.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

.logo,
ul {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.55rem;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani';
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.75);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.25);
}

.logo {
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.7rem;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.phrase {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}

.phrase p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo';
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.phrase a {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Bitter';
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.phrase a:hover {
  background-color: #cc2900;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.phrase .fas {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/*---ABOUT---*/

.stats {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px grey;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.stats div {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.stats p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1);
  font-family: 'Rajdhani';
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.stats div:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.60);
}

.about .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('img/concrete.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.about h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani';
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  word-spacing: 7px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

.underline {
  width: 100px;
  height: 2.5px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.about p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo';
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}


/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Kane Concrete And Construction LLC</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="after">Home</li>
          <li class="after">About</li>
          <li class="after">Services</li>
          <li class="after">Job Openings</li>
          <li class="after">Gallery</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="phrase">
      <p>It all starts at the foundation.</p>
      <a>Get a Quote</a>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="stats">
      <div id="start-year">
        <p>Established</p><br>
        <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">2015</p>
      </div>

      <div id="projects">
        <p>Projects</p><br>
        <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">200+</p>
      </div>

      <div id="claims">
        <p>Insurance claims</p><br>
        <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">87%</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section class="about">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <div class="underline"></div>

        <p><span style="color: red;">W</span>e believe that Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum doloremque impedit laudantium magnam eos quae ipsum, rem, dolorum saepe laboriosam ipsam nobis architecto debitis, vel aut provident
          tenetur perferendis, aliquid commodi magni sequi hic quia nemo! Nam odio fugiat, similique eum saepe. Laboriosam officiis delectus reiciendis, est tenetur voluptates ducimus! Ducimus enim dolor, eos id porro, amet culpa alias sunt reprehenderit
          necessitatibus deserunt eum. Sunt quia accusamus facilis quo, cum maiores nam illum sit quisquam, tempora fugit? Quod voluptate debitis voluptatum illo. Est, rerum sequi. Corporis atque incidunt placeat aliquam error veniam quis, minus voluptatem,
          qui, a pariatur voluptatibus, ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe labore aliquid magnam velit, nisi consequuntur!</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="footer">
      <div class="wrapper">

      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is...

You can have a wrapper around the body of your page (my example calls it `inner-wrap`). At the bottom of your page, have another div *(sibling to `inner-wrap`)* that pushes the bottom of the page up just enough that the fixed footer would be visible - if the second div had a transparent background... So, give the 2nd div a transparent background.

So the point is that the push-up div and the footer need to be the same height.

*Note: I made the footer div (and the footer-window div) only 150px high so they could be seen in the snippet window without going full-screen.*

```css
body, html{margin:0;padding:0;}

/*---HEADER---*/
#inner-wrap{background:pink;}
header{background-image:url(img/wall2.jpeg);height:100vh;background-attachment:fixed;}

nav{background-color:white;width:100%;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;box-shadow:0px 0px 100px grey;}

.logo, ul{flex-basis:30%;list-style-type:none;}

ul{margin-right:30px;margin-top:25px;}

li{display:inline-block;font-size:1.55rem;margin-right:20px;font-family:'Rajdhani';color:rgba(102,102,102,0.75);}

li:hover{cursor:pointer;color:#1a1a1a;transition:all 0.7s ease;}

.after:after{position:relative;left:12px;top:2px;display:inline-block;content:"";width:1px;height:20px;background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.25);}

.logo{color:red;font-size:3.7rem;margin:10px;opacity:1;margin-left:30px;}

.phrase{text-align:center;position:relative;top:300px;}

.phrase p{color:white;font-size:3.5rem;font-family:'Arvo';margin-bottom:30px;}

.phrase a{background-color:red;border-radius:25px;color:white;font-family:'Bitter';font-size:1.8rem;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;}

.phrase a:hover{background-color:#cc2900;transition:all 0.2s ease;cursor:pointer;}

.phrase .fas{display:block;color:white;font-size:3.5rem;margin-top:15px;}

/*---ABOUT---*/

.stats{width:100%;display:flex;box-shadow:0px 0px 150px grey;position:relative;z-index:1;}

.stats div{display:inline-block;flex-basis:35%;text-align:center;padding-bottom:30px;}
.stats p{font-size:2rem;color:rgba(102,102,102, 1);font-family:'Rajdhani';margin-bottom:0;margin-top:10px;}
.stats div:before{display:inline-block;content:'';width:2px;height:35px;background-color:rgba(102,102,102, 0.60);}
.about .wrapper{width:100%;background-image:url('img/concrete.jpg');background-position:center;background-attachment:fixed;background-size:cover;}
.about h1{position:relative;top:40px;color:white;font-family:'Rajdhani';font-size:4rem;text-align:center;margin-top:0;word-spacing:7px;text-shadow:0px 0px 100px grey;}
.underline{width:100px;height:2.5px;background-color:red;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-top:-15px;border-radius:4px;}
.about p{color:white;font-size:1.8rem;font-family:'Arvo';margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:60px;text-align:center;margin-top:40px;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;}

/*---FOOTER---*/
.footer-window{width:100%;height:150px;background:transparent;}
.footer{width:100%;background-color:purple;height:150px;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:-1;padding:20px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Kane Concrete And Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="inner-wrap">
 <header>
  <nav>
   <div class="logo">
    <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
   </div>

   <div class="nav">
    <ul>
     <li class="after">Home</li>
     <li class="after">About</li>
     <li class="after">Services</li>
     <li class="after">Job Openings</li>
     <li class="after">Gallery</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="phrase">
   <p>It all starts at the foundation.</p>
   <a>Get a Quote</a>
   <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <main>
  <div class="stats">
   <div id="start-year">
    <p>Established</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">2015</p>
   </div>

   <div id="projects">
    <p>Projects</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">200+</p>
   </div>

   <div id="claims">
    <p>Insurance claims</p><br>
    <p style="color: red; font-size: 2.3rem; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: bold;">87%</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <section class="about">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <div class="underline"></div>

    <p><span style="color: red;">W</span>e believe that Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum doloremque impedit laudantium magnam eos quae ipsum, rem, dolorum saepe laboriosam ipsam nobis architecto debitis, vel aut provident tenetur perferendis, aliquid commodi magni sequi hic quia nemo! Nam odio fugiat, similique eum saepe. Laboriosam officiis delectus reiciendis, est tenetur voluptates ducimus! Ducimus enim dolor, eos id porro, amet culpa alias sunt reprehenderit necessitatibus deserunt eum. Sunt quia accusamus facilis quo, cum maiores nam illum sit quisquam, tempora fugit? Quod voluptate debitis voluptatum illo. Est, rerum sequi. Corporis atque incidunt placeat aliquam error veniam quis, minus voluptatem, qui, a pariatur voluptatibus, ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe labore aliquid magnam velit, nisi consequuntur!</p>
   </div>
  </section>
  </div>
    <section class="footer-window"></section>

  <section class="footer">
   <div class="wrapper">
    This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. This is the footer. 
   </div>
  </section>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked, can you help me figure out why the footer is still layered over the stats section.

Comment: Sure - post another question with the new code and I'll do my best. After posting the new question, just add another note here with the link to the new question *(use the SHARE link under your new question)*

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple if you understand the Z-index property properly, that being said it's not too hard to mis-understand it. CSS-Tricks has a pretty good article about the subject [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

If you take a look at my sample below you can see a simplified version of what after, I've commented the code so you can understand the steps.

```css
/* Make sure the body is set to relative to root the document flow again. */

body {
  position: relative;
}


/* -- Wrap the page content and lift it from the document flow. */

.page-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* change the layer position  up the dom stack*/
  z-index: 999;
}


/* re-wrap the content and place a white background on it */

.page-wrap .content-wrap {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/* here is our window for the footer */

.spacer {
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
}


/* finally fix the footer to the bottom of the browser window */

.tucked-footer {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -999;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Tucked footer</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- We add this spacer to act like a window -->
  <div class="spacer">
  </div>

</div>

<footer class="tucked-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non sapien mattis, tempor erat ac, dignissim ipsum. Vestibulum dapibus turpis vel tincidunt condimentum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

> **[ORIGINAL FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/zogbek4t/28/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you can you help me figure out why the footer is layered over the stats section? I read through that link and still couldn't figure it out